# PHP: `strptime()` alternative in Windows

Tags: php, linux, windows, date, strptime

My current PHP library doesn't work in Windows because `strptime()` function is not implemented in Windows.

> Note: This function is not implemented on Windows platforms.

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strptime.php

Does anyone know any alternative alternative function or way around it? Thanks!

To make it clearer, for example, I want to parse `7 Jun 2016 7:00` using format `%e %b %Y %k:%M`

Comment: Currently trying. The usage seems different

Comment: top comment on the page you linked in your question would appear to be aimed at windows users

Comment: Yup, but it doesn't support `%b`. I already solved my own problem though, by ignoring `strptime` and change the whole code. I'll still keep this question open to help anyone